What proportion of the total fuel load in a Saturn V was used to drive the pumps?
In a liquid propellant rocket, power is needed to pump propellant against the pressure inside the combustion chamber. The Rocketdyne F-1 reportedly used 55,000 HP to drive the pumps.
What proportion of the total fuel load in a Saturn V was used to drive the pumps? How does this compare with newer engines?
How does this compare with the pump energy used in the Electron rocket? Starship?

Output of the engine seems to be 160,000,000 horsepower, so about 0.03 percent.

Jets and rockets can't really by rated by horsepower since the definition of HP involves work/time. The work done by a rocket is totally application dependent. An F-1 in a test stand produces zero HP.

Why would a rocket in a test stand do no work? It might not be moving the earth very far when it's fired but it will be having an effect and the earth is very heavy, it'll still be doing the same amount of work (bar efficiency changes due to different conditions)

@AlanBirtles ... work = force X distance. Tiny distance = tiny work. The calculated horsepower of a rocket depends on its speed, so the "horsepower" is not an inherent property of the rocket engine.

I found a F-1 technical manual. 1
The mass flow rates of fuel are 1758 lb/s from the pump and 121.1 lb/s to the gas generator.
The mass flow rates of oxidizer are 3986 and 50.4 lb/s.
So 1.26 % of the oxygen was used for the turbine and 6.88 % of the fuel. The gas generator was run fuel rich to limit the temperature of the gas into the  turbine. In total 2.98 % of the propellants are needed to to drive the pumps.
Only 3% of the total propellants load in a Saturn V first stage was used to drive the pumps.
The cryogenic J-2 engine for the second and third stages needed 0.757 % of the LOX and 4.43 % of the LH2 to drive the pumps. That is only 1.32 % of the propellants.

How does this compare to newer engines?
